# Hibernate identity generator issue

Tags: java, hibernate

I am having a particular issue when trying to save a collection of objects with hibernate. It seems that when I have more than one object of the same type, hibernate fails to generate the identifier, so I get a `org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException` .

Example:

App1 --> urls
{strApplicationId:1;URLTypeEntity{strCode:1,strDescription:Reply},strURL:www.address1.com},
{strApplicationId:1;URLTypeEntity{strCode:1,strDescription:Reply},strURL:www.address2.com},
{strApplicationId:1;URLTypeEntity{strCode:2,strDescription:Home},strURL:www.address3.com}

If I do not have two URLs with the same URLTypeEntity on the collection, the error is not triggered

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_urls")
public class URLEntity
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="intCode")
    private Integer intCode;
    private String strApplicationID;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "intType", referencedColumnName = "intCode")
    private URLTypeEntity objURLType;
    private String strURL;
}
@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_applications")
public class ApplicationEntity
{
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "strApplicationID")
    private List<URLEntity> colURLs;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was changing the CascadeType from ALL To Merge

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "strApplicationID")
Changed To

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, mappedBy = "strApplicationID")

Answer (score 1):

`ApplicationEntity` must also have an id.